# ¿Cómo listar cajas abiertas y cerradas en unión de tablas MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysqli, mariadb

He creado una tabla llamada `tbl_cashier` que es para la apertura y cierre de caja de un sistema de ventas, dónde en la columna `status` indica si es `0` está abierta y `1` está cerrada tomando en cuanta el `id_seller`:

[image]

Luego tengo la tabla `tbl_invoice` que es donde se registran todas las ventas realizadas por el usuario:

[image]

Considerando lo deseado he realizado la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT
    ca.id_cashier,
    ca.open_date,
    ca.open_amount,
    ca.close_date,
    SUM(i.amount_total) AS sales_day,
    ca.open_amount + SUM(i.amount_total) AS total_amount,
    ca.cashier_status
    FROM tbl_cashier ca
    LEFT JOIN tbl_invoice i ON ca.id_seller=i.id_seller
    WHERE ca.id_seller=6
AND (
  (i.payer_date BETWEEN ca.open_date AND ca.close_date)
  or
  (ca.close_date IS NULL AND i.payer_date > ca.open_date)
 )
GROUP BY 1 DESC
```

Y, aquí adjunto la salida:

[image]

El resultado es correcto, se observa que existe una caja cerrada la misma que tiene un saldo de apertura de `100.00` más dos ventas `10.00` + `10.10` que ha realizado desde la apertura hasta el cierre, tendiendo un total de `120.10`.

Hasta allí va todo bien, pero ¿Cómo puedo listar ambos casos, es decir cajas abiertas `0` y cajas cerradas `1`? ya que sino se muestra las cajas aperturadas el usuario no podrá ejecutar el `botón` cerrar caja.

En el siguiente demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7Ztfb8HhrxUPbb7jE6S4o2/1 se observa que no esta tomando en cuenta las cajas abiertas.

El resultado deseado:

| id_cashier | open_date | open_amount | close_date | cashier_status | sales_day | total_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2022-11-08 04:42:00 | 10 | null | 0 | 00.00 | 10.00 |
| 2 | 2022-11-01 00:23:12 | 10 | 2022-11-08 04:15:14 | 1 | 0 | 10 |
| 1 | 2022-10-28 10:52:59 | 100 | 2022-10-28 23:29:42 | 1 | 20.1 | 120.1 |

Comment: Las cajas abiertas tienen el close_date en NULL, así que la condición del between para el payer_date no va a funcionar muy bien... _la fácil_ sería hacer un UNION de las dos consultas, una para abiertas y otra para cerradas.

Comment: @Alfabravo Ya veo, no he usado `UNION` lo voy a investigar,  gracias

Comment: No es del todo un [ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Si quitaras las columnas que no se involucran en la consulta nos quitarías *"ruido"* y nos ayudarías a ayudarte. Prueba con `WHERE ca.id_seller = 6 AND i.payer_date BETWEEN ca.open_date AND ifnull(ca.close_date, now())`.

Comment: @Sal Amigo solo están pocas columnas y que son importantes en la apertura y cierre de caja, tengo vinculadas otras tablas `LEFT JOIN` pero solo he dejado las del problema para no confundir en la pregunta.

Comment: Me refiero mas a las columnas de tbl_invoice del fiddle. También deberías agregar un ejemplo del resultado esperado a partir de tus datos de ejemplo.

Comment: @Sal No funciona, solo me lista las cajas cerradas y por lo que veo para que liste las cajas abiertas primero tiene que existir una venta por ese usuario y después aperturar la caja pero esa lógica está mal ya que primero es la apertura de caja y después la venta https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7Ztfb8HhrxUPbb7jE6S4o2/2

Comment: @Sal Ah, pero de esa tabla solo se toman en cuenta tres columnas `id_seller, payer_date` nada más

Comment: @Sal ya agregué amigo el resultado deseado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es con el where, que te filtra los resultados que tú quieres, específicamente `i.payer_date > ca.open_date`, porque esa condición puede no cumplirse cuando una caja está abierta. Entonces lo que hay que hacer es moverla al left join para el cruce de ambas tablas considere esa condición

Por último hay que usar [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) para controlar los valores de la suma, porque en una caja abierta, la suma de ventas puede ser nula

```
SELECT
    ca.id_cashier,
    ca.open_date,
    ca.open_amount,
    ca.close_date,
    COALESCE(SUM(i.amount_total),0) AS sales_day,
    ca.open_amount + COALESCE(SUM(i.amount_total),0) AS total_amount,
    ca.cashier_status
    FROM tbl_cashier ca
    left JOIN tbl_invoice i ON ca.id_seller=i.id_seller AND i.payer_date > ca.open_date
    WHERE ca.id_seller=6
AND (
  (i.payer_date BETWEEN ca.open_date AND ca.close_date)
  or
  (ca.close_date IS NULL )
 )
GROUP BY ca.id_cashier
```

Resultado:

| id_cashier | open_date | open_amount | close_date | cashier_status | sales_day | total_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-28 10:52:59 | 100 | 2022-10-28 23:29:42 | 1 | 20.1 | 120.1 |
| 2 | 2022-11-01 00:23:12 | 10 | 2022-11-08 04:15:14 | 1 | 0 | 10 |
| 4 | 2022-11-08 04:42:00 | 10 | null | 0 | 0 | 10 |

Answer (score 1):

No creo que sea necesario usar `union`. Y puedes hacer todo desde la misma consulta. Dado que si la caja sigue abierta, solo necesitas que la fecha sea mayor a la apertura, puedes hacer algo como esto.

```
WHERE ca.id_seller=6
AND (
  (i.payer_date BETWEEN ca.open_date AND ca.close_date)
  or
  (ca.close_date IS NULL AND i.payer_date > ca.open_date)
 )
```

De esta forma sumas todo lo que esté dentro de la fecha de apertura al día de hoy.

Comment: Amigo no me muestra las cajas apertura das solo las cerradas https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7Ztfb8HhrxUPbb7jE6S4o2/1

Answer (score 1):

Yo a veces he tenido problemas similares y opte por mantener dos tablas...una para cajas abiertas y otra para cerradas. Luego usar Union de  dos consultas una cada tabla. A la larga me fue bien porque el comportamiento es distinto y por tanto tendrán campos distintos...pe observaciones de porque no se cerro esa caja.

Por tanto, aseguro y puedo asegurar que tu problema viene de crear un campo *cashier_status* para agrupar dos objetos que en realidad son distintos.
La solución ya la he dicho tener una tabla para cajas abiertas y otra cerrada.
Evidentemente en cajas abiertas no existirá el campo *close_date*, un nulo que te quitas de encima. No digo mas que yo cobro por esto...